# Terraform launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm creating aws eks cluster via terraform, but when i create cluster nodegroup with launch template i got 2 launch templates - one is with name and settings that i specify and second is with random name but with setting that i specify. Only difference in this 2 launch templat is IAM instance profile that got 2nd group (that creates automatically).
If i trying to specify IAM instance profile in my group it gives error that i cannot use it here
Is i'm doing something wrong or it's normal that it's creates 2 launch template ?

```
# eks node launch template
resource "aws_launch_template" "this" {
  name          = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-node-launch-template"
  instance_type = var.instance_types[0]
  image_id      = var.node_ami

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 80
      volume_type = "gp3"
      throughput  = "125"
      encrypted   = false
      iops        = 3000
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  network_interfaces {
    security_groups = [data.aws_eks_cluster.this.vpc_config[0].cluster_security_group_id]
  }

  user_data = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/userdata.tpl", merge(local.userdata_vars, local.cluster_data)))

  tags = {
    "eks:cluster-name"   = var.eks_cluster_name
    "eks:nodegroup-name" = var.node_group_name
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name                 = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-node"
      "eks:cluster-name"   = var.eks_cluster_name
      "eks:nodegroup-name" = var.node_group_name
    }
  }
  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "volume"

    tags = {
      "eks:cluster-name"   = var.eks_cluster_name
      "eks:nodegroup-name" = var.node_group_name
    }
  }
}
```

```
# eks nodes
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "this" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.this.name
  node_group_name = var.node_group_name
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eksNodesGroup.arn
  subnet_ids      = data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 10
    min_size     = 1
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  launch_template {
    version = aws_launch_template.this.latest_version
    id      = aws_launch_template.this.id
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [
      scaling_config[0].desired_size
    ]
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Node Group handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EC2 Instances and Elastic Network Interfaces.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
    aws_launch_template.this
  ]
}
```

Expecting that terraform will create one launch template

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't see any for_each or other loops so I'd expect only one. Unless you have draft code somewhere or running terraform in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute `name` by `name_prefix`

Use:

`name_prefix   = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-node-launch-template"`

Instead of:

`name          = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-node-launch-template"`

The best choice to create a Unique name for a launch template using prefix (in your case `${var.eks_cluster_name}`) is the name_prefix attribute.

Read more [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#name_prefix)

Comment: changed code for name_prefix and it's still creates 2 launch-template and one that i created now got random digits after name (test-users-node-launch-template20220407120132892600000007)

Comment: Ups, well, I have more than 1 deploy using this way and I don't have repeated launch templates.